# multiply list of matrices by the list of arrays where they are from different length in R

Tags: r

I would like to multiply matrices by arrays where they have different lengths.

## Note: the multiplication should be element by the matches element.

1- I have a list of two matrices.

2- I have a list of arrays (three arrays for each element of the list).

I would like to do the following:

3- Multiply the first matrix by the 3 arrays of the first element of the arrays list.

4- Multiply the second matrix by the 3 arrays of the second element of the arrays list.

Then the expected output would be:

1- 3 arrays from the multiplication of the first matrix by the 3 arrays.

2- 3 arrays from the second multiplication.

However, I only got 3 arrays.

I can do that manually but I would like to do it automatically.

Here is the code:

```
set.seed(47)
a <- vector('list', 2)
for( i in seq_along(a)){       
  a[[i]] <- array(rnorm(5 * 5 * 3), c(5, 5, 3))
}

we1 <- c(0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9,
         0, 0, 0.1, 0.6, 0.9,
         0, 0, 0, 0.9, 0.5,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
we1 <- matrix(we1, 5, 5)
we2 <- c(0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.9,
         0, 0, 0.1, 0.6, 0.9,
         0, 0, 0, 0.9, 0.5,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
we2 <- matrix(we2, 5, 5)
we <- list(we1, we2)

x <- vector("list",2)
for(j in 1:2){
for( i in 1:3){
  x[[i]] <-  we[[j]]*a[[j]][[i]]
}
}
```

The output:

```
> x
[[1]]
           [,1]        [,2]       [,3]       [,4] [,5]
[1,]  0.0000000  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.0000000    0
[2,] -0.1878045  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.0000000    0
[3,] -0.4695112 -0.09390224  0.0000000  0.0000000    0
[4,] -0.4695112 -0.56341343 -0.8451202  0.0000000    0
[5,] -0.8451202 -0.84512015 -0.4695112 -0.7512179    0

[[2]]
          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4] [,5]
[1,] 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000    0
[2,] 0.1676886 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000    0
[3,] 0.4192215 0.08384429 0.0000000 0.0000000    0
[4,] 0.4192215 0.50306575 0.7545986 0.0000000    0
[5,] 0.7545986 0.75459863 0.4192215 0.6707543    0

[[3]]
          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4] [,5]
[1,] 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000    0
[2,] 0.1058393 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.0000000    0
[3,] 0.2645984 0.05291967 0.0000000 0.0000000    0
[4,] 0.2645984 0.31751803 0.4762770 0.0000000    0
[5,] 0.4762770 0.47627705 0.2645984 0.4233574    0
```

Any help, please?

Comment: Do you need `lapply(seq_along(we), function(i) a[[i]]*array(we[[i]], dim(a[[i]])))`

Comment: It is amazing. Thanks so much.

Comment: You are looping through `i` and `j` index, but storing only by one index `i` in `x[[i]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can either use `lapply` or `Map`.  As the number of `list` elements are the same for 'a' and 'we', but only only one of them is `array` i.e. 'a', we can `replicate` the 'we' by the third dimension of `a[[i]]`

```
Map(function(x, y) x*replicate(dim(x)[3], y), a, we)
```

---

Or loop through the sequence of `list` elements and do the multiplication after `replication` as mentioned above

```
lapply(seq_along(we), function(i) a[[i]]*array(we[[i]], dim(a[[i]])))
```

Here, we use `array`, which will do the recycling of the elements and subsequent replication before multiplying.

---

If we are using `for` loop

```
for(i in seq_along(x)) x[[i]] <- replicate(dim(a[[i]])[3], we[[i]]) * a[[i]]
```

Comment: It is great. Could you also, provide how we can do it in the same idea I did in my question using `for` loop, please?

Comment: GREAT as usual!